# Hide rows based on Date input

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Sheet, `Data24h`, that is filled with data sorted by date.

I want to create the function for the user to just show data from a specific date.

So I created an `UserForm` where the user inputs a date in `textbox1` and then I want the program to hide every row that is not included in the date interval.

The hide-function seems to work but the condition does not work. If I have today's date as YYMMDD as input it will still show all dates.

I am new to programing in general and VBA in particular and understand if the question is a bit vague and most probably the code looks like #!!#@.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Datum = TextBox1.Value
    Sheets("Data24h").Select
    BeginRow = "" 
    EndRow = 100 
    ChkCol = 3 

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value >= Datum Then
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next RowCnt

    Columns("A").Select 
    Unload Me 
    Återställ1.Show 
End Sub
```

So I tried using Autofilter but still can't manage. Now I get an error 1004 in the "last" autofilter row. As I understand it I get this error because autofilter believes the range to be empty?

EDIT: I did it! Autofilter solved it! I just missed := in Fields. Thanks everyone for your efforts.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Datum As Date
Dim Datum_l As Long

Sheets("Data24h").Select

Datum = CDate(Me.TextBox1.Value)

With Data24h
    AutoFilterMode = False
    Selection.Range("A2:A100").AutoFilter
    Selection.Range("A2:A100").AutoFilter Field = 1, Criteria1:=">=" & Datum

End With
```

Comment: Where is your declaration? Did you try debugging?

Comment: Using an `Autofilter` would be a very easy way to go. It can filter your data by a specific date (today, yesterday, March 1) or by a date range (last month, this quarter, March 1 to March 14).

Comment: The cells & columns collections don't immediately appear to have a bearing or reference here (unless they're declared outside of the method). You might want to try adding THISWORKBOOK.WORKSHEETS("SHEET1").CELLS instead of just CELLS. The same for COLUMNS. Also, can't you just use Excel's built in filtering here - do you need VBA?

Comment: I have been looking into Autofilter but havent been able to get it to work either. Maybe this is better anyway?

In worst case I will use the built in filtering but I guess this forces the operators of the program to be able to filter it?

Answer (score 0):

First off all add a declaration for the Datum variable (Dim Datum As Date)
Next Rewrite the line setting the date to Datum = CDate(TextBox1.Value)

This is just to get you started. It makes the comparison between the value in the textbox and the values in the cells better (assuming the values in the cells are true dates)

Comment: Thank you! CDate seems to be right approach and the cells in the other Sheet is formated as Date. But the comparision still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, I added `CDate()` function to convert data to a typed Date might ease this, but yoy may need to check the input value that people can enter into your textbox.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim Datum As Date, _
        BeginRow As Integer, _
        EndRow As Double, _
        ChkCol As Integer, _
        Ws As Worksheet

    Set Ws = Sheets("Data24h")
    Datum = CDate(Me.TextBox1.Value)
    BeginRow = 1
    EndRow = Ws.Range(Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ChkCol = 3

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If CDate(Ws.Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value) >= Datum Then
            Ws.Rows(RowCnt).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Else
            Ws.Rows(RowCnt).EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next RowCnt

    'Columns("A").Select
    Unload Me
    Återställ1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 

I assume Cdate() is the right approach but I still can't get it to work. The cells in the sheet Data24h are defined as Date . When printing the Datum into a cell it shows up as the input date in the format YYYY-MM-DD but the comparision between the input value and the existing cell still does not seem to work.

Comment: Best thing is to give some details on the formating you want in the label next to your textbox because dates can be formatted in so many different ways!
Have you tried with a clean formated date in your textbox?

Comment: I want the operator to give the date in the format YYYY-MM-DD. Though I haven't defined this it at all my textbox looks just as this:

Private Sub TextBox1_Change()

End Sub

Edit: Managed to press return to quickly. Seems like I cant add any code in this comment? Sorry about that. Is the problem that I dont define what kind of input that I want from the textbox?

Comment: The easiest way to check if you have a date, is to use `IsDate()` function, after this it'll be much more heavy. And to sensibilise people using your tool, specify the format that you want in a `Label` close to your `TextBox`. To debug, use `MsgBox` and `Chr(13)` rather than a cell in Excel that will probably reformat your data, so display both in there, separated with the `Chr(13)`.